# I have Windows 10 in developer mode and am using the BASH kernel. Where are my files?

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I activated developer mode and also the BASH kernel, so now I can use Linux functionality (with some limits, mostly related to permissions) on my Windows machine.

when I open a bash session and type:

```
cd / && ls -l
```

I get a list of folders, one being `/mnt`.  Inside of `mnt` there is a folder called `c`.  This is the "C" drive and I can traverse there for operations.

My question is, bash knows the windows environment, but where is the bash files like `/home` and `/var` and `/etc` located on my windows machine?  I.e. what path?  Or are they a binary object file that is not accessible?  Knowing this would be very helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/759880/where-is-the-ubuntu-file-system-root-directory-in-windows-nt-subsystem-and-vice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your profile (`%localappdata%\lxss`), but do not try to access them from Windows or you will corrupt your files, since special data is stored in the NTFS metadata.

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/

> DO NOT, under ANY circumstances, create and/or modify Linux files using Windows apps, tools, scripts, consoles, etc.

For more details about how things are stored see this article.

- DevFS https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/06/15/wsl-file-system-support/